# Nested CASE expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two radio buttons in UI, and column of that radio buttons in table is nullable, in getbyid stored procedure first I want to check if column is null then return null, if it is not null then check if it is zero(No) then return zero or if it is 1(YES) then return one, I think I have to use nested CASE statement for this but can't figure out actual statement, any help please? I have tried the following:

```
CASE WHEN TMC.CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN(CASE TMC.CUSTOMER_ID WHEN 0 THEN 0 
                                                                ELSE 1) 
     ELSE NULL END AS CustomerId,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `END` from the second `CASE` is missing

```
CASE 
  WHEN TMC.CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL 
  THEN 
    CASE TMC.CUSTOMER_ID WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  ELSE NULL 
END                                                     AS CustomerId,
```

you can achieve the same result with the SIGN function

```
SIGN(TMC.CUSTOMER_ID) AS CustomerId
```

or with ABS and SIGN if the customerId could be negative

```
SIGN(ABS(TMC.CUSTOMER_ID)) AS CustomerId
```

Answer (score 2):

```
CASE
  WHEN TMC.CUSTOMER_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
      CASE WHEN TMC.CUSTOMER_ID=0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
END   as type_pre,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Oracle function [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) with `null` value as default:

```
 decode( TMC.CUSTOMER_ID, 0, 0, 1, 1, null)
```

[image]